# flutter depends on firebase_analytics 0.0.4 which requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter

Because flutter_chat_app depends on firebase_analytics 0.0.4 which requires SDK version >=1.8.0 <2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1)
exit code 1

```
 dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  image_picker: 0.1.1
  google_sign_in: 0.3.1
  firebase_analytics: 0.0.4
  firebase_auth: 0.2.0
  firebase_database: 0.0.12
  firebase_storage: 0.0.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your dependency have version constraints that request quite outdated versions of dependencies.

Check each dependency in https://pub.dartlang.org and change the version constraint to versions that allow the version you want

```
image_picker: ^0.5.0
```

which allows all version `0.5.x`

or

```
google_sign_in: ^4.0.0
```

which allows all versions `4.x.x`

Please note the different effect of `^` for versions that start with `0.` vs versions that start with `1.` (or any other number other than `0`.

Please also check the `CHANGELOG.md` tab. Most "official" plugins require you to migrate your project to AndroidX.

Answer (score 0):

Just come down to the issue, you have to add dev dependency. you can add something called dependency override into the pubspec file.

like that :

dependency_overrides:
    
image_picker: ^0.5.0